# Regex Match Reset \K Equalent In Java

Tags: java, regex, java-11

I have come up with a regex pattern to match a part of a Json value. But only PRCE engine is supporting this. I want to know the Java equalent of this regex.

Simplified version

```
cif:\K.*(?=(.+?){4})
```

Matches part of the value, leaving the last 4 characters.

cif:**test**1234

Matched value will be **test**

https://regex101.com/r/xV4ZNa/1

*Note: I can only define the regex and the replace text. I don't have access to the Java code since it's handle by a propriotery log masking framework.*

Comment: “*I can only define the regex and the replace text.*” Well, then you are not bound to this construct at all. Just let your replacement text start with `cif:` and it’s as if the `cif:` prefix wasn’t part of the match…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write simplify the  pattern to:

```
(?<=cif:).*(?=....)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=cif:)` Positive lookbehind, assert `cif:` to the left
- `.*` Match 0+ times any character without newlines
- `(?=....)` Positive lookahead, assert 4 characters (which can include spaces)

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Izud6j/1).

If you don't want to match empty strings, then you can use `.+` instead

```
(?<=cif:).+(?=....)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookbehind assertion instead:

```
(?<=cif:).*(?=(.+?){4})
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xV4ZNa/3